# jquery sortable nested & connected issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using a nested & connected sortable container.

```
<div id="pagebuilder">

<div class="sortable-el text">
  <span class="name">Text 1</span>
</div>

<div class="sortable-el section">
  <span class="name">Section 1</span>
  <div class="section-inner">
    <div class="sortable-el text">
      <span class="name">Text 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sortable-el section">
  <span class="name">Section 2</span>
  <div class="section-inner">
    <div class="sortable-el text">
      <span class="name">Text 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sortable-el text">
      <span class="name">Text 4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLzU3/377/)

It kind of works, but I'm experiencing some issues:

1. I have different types of sortable elements (text + section).   The
   text element can be placed into the main sortable container & the
   nested container (pagebuilder + section-inner).  But I'm trying to
   prevent that a section element can be dragged into another section
   element (try dragging the section 1 into the section 2, this should
   not be possible). Section elements should not be nested.
2. When a Section element is empty (drag the text2 out of the section
   1), it's not possible to read an element to it (try to drag any
   text element to the empty section, it does not work)

Am I missing something?

Comment: #2 is caused by the `section-inner` element having no height when you drag the last element out of it. You can fix this by adding a `min-height` to it: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ZLzU3/378/

Comment: Thanks for the quick help on this.  Do you have any idea how to solve for #1?